# Circular import of db reference using Flask-SQLAlchemy and Blueprints

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy, flask

I am using Flask-SQLAlchemy and Blueprints and I cannot help myself from using circular imports. 
I know I can write imports inside functions and make it work but it sounds nasty, I'd like to confirm with the community if there is a better way to do this.

The problem is I have a module (blueprints.py) where I declare the database and import the blueprints but those blueprints need to import the database declaration at the same time.

This is the code (excerpt of the important parts):

### application.apps.people.views.py

```
from application.blueprints import db

people = Blueprint('people', __name__,
                 template_folder='templates',
                 static_folder='static')

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)

@people.route('/all')
def all():
    users = User.query.all()
```

### application.blueprints.py

```
from application.apps.people.views import people

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////tmp/test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
app.register_blueprint(people, url_prefix='/people')
```

I have read the documentation and the questions I found on this topic, but I still cannot find the answer I am looking for.
I have found this chapter (https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/contexts.html) where it suggest to put the initialization code inside a method but the circular import still persist.

**Edit**
I fixed the problem using the pattern [Application Factory](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/appfactories/)

Comment: could you please share the code ?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

I fixed the problem with the help of the [Application Factory](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/appfactories/) pattern. I declare the database in a third module and configure it later in the same module in which I start the application.

This results in the following imports:

- database.py → app.py
- views.py → app.py
- database.py → views.py

There is no circular import. It is important to make sure that the application was started and configured before calling database operations.

Here is an example application:

**app.py**

```
from database import db
from flask import Flask
import os.path
from views import User
from views import people


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['DEBUG'] = True
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "sqlite:////tmp/test.db"
    db.init_app(app)    
    app.register_blueprint(people, url_prefix='')
    return app 


def setup_database(app):
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
    user = User()
    user.username = "Tom"
    db.session.add(user)
    db.session.commit()    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = create_app()
    # Because this is just a demonstration we set up the database like this.
    if not os.path.isfile('/tmp/test.db'):
      setup_database(app)
    app.run()
```

**database.py**

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()
```

**views.py**

```
from database import db
from flask.blueprints import Blueprint


people = Blueprint('people', __name__,
                 template_folder='templates',
                 static_folder='static')


class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)


@people.route('/')
def test():
  user = User.query.filter_by(username="Tom").first()
  return "Test: Username %s " % user.username
```

Comment: could you provide a github repo with this approach?

Comment: nailed it. great solution.

Comment: when views.py and app.py imports db, does that not make db two different objects? Is that an issue?

Answer (score 30):

Circular imports in Flask are driving me nuts. From the docs: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/packages/

> ... Be advised that this is a bad idea in general but here it is actually fine.

It is not fine. **It is deeply wrong.** I also consider putting any code in `__init__.py` as a bad practice.   It makes the application harder to scale. Blueprints is a way to alleviate the problem with circular imports. I think Flask needs more of this.

Comment: Putting the core app code in an app/__init__.py file seems to be pretty common:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-structure-large-flask-applications

https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/wiki/Large-app-how-to

and even in the O'Reily Flask Web Applications book

Comment: Could you offer some pointers for how Blueprints help avoid circulars?

Answer (score 21):

I know this has been solved already, but I solved this in a slightly different way and wanted to answer in case it helps others.

Originally, my application code (e.g. `my_app.py`) had this line:

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

And so in my `models.py`, I had:

```
from my_app import db

class MyModel(db.Model):
    # etc
```

hence the circular references when using `MyModel` in `my_app`.

I updated this so that `models.py` had this:

```
# models.py

from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()  # note no "app" here, and no import from my_app above

class MyModel(db.Model):
    # etc as before
```

and then in `my_app.py`:

```
# my_app.py

from models import db, MyModel  # importing db is new

# ...

db.init_app(app)  # call init_app here rather than initialising db here
```

Comment: What happens if you multiple model files? Would they all have to `from models import db`?

Comment: @PaymahnMoghadasian I have multiple model classes in `models.py`.  If you had multiple files with models in, that would be more complicated - you'd need to move `db = SQLAlchemy()` to a separate file which both the models and the application imported from, I think (but note that I've not tried this).

Comment: This works in the simple case that you described in your answer but it would become quite problematic if you were to have multiple models defined in separate files.

Answer (score 3):

Serge, bring out definition of models in a separate file called `models.py`.
Register blueprint in  `__init__.py` file of the package.

You've got circular import because blueprint file trying to import people reference from `views.py`, but in `views.py` you're trying to import db from `blueprints.py`. And all of this is done at the top level of the modules.

You can make your project structure like this:

```
app
  __init__.py  # registering of blueprints and db initialization
  mods
    __init__.py
    people
      __init__.py  # definition of module (blueprint)
      views.py  # from .models import User
      models.py # from app import db
```

**UPD:**

For those who are in the tank:

`people/__init__.py` --> `mod = Module('app.mods.people', 'people')`

`people/views.py` --> `@mod.route('/page')`

`app/__init__.py` --> `from app.mods import people; from app.mods.people import views; app.register_blueprint(people.mod, **options);`

Comment: Thanks. Indeed I have the models definition separated but for this circular import dilemma it makes no difference because I have to import models from the view module. What are the reasons to register the blueprint in init.py?

Comment: @Serge, I've corrected my answer and gave you just about right structure for your project.

Comment: It didn't work, because @people.route('/all') is never initialized with the view function if I put view and blueprint separated.

Comment: Ohh..  Updated my answer, I advise you before you write to read at least a little documentation...

Comment: The update also contains a circular import: people/views imports db from app/__init__ and app/__init__ imports people/views. Also the use of Module is not necessary in this case. Thanks anyway. What I am doing now is to encapsulate the app initialization inside a create_app() pushing db outside and using flask.current_app to access the app values in runtime.

Comment: You should register blueprints and import views after db creation at `app/__init__.py` and this helps you to avoid circular import. Anyway, encapsulating creation in func is good approach, especially when you will test it later.

Comment: I know that, although it works it is still a circular import.