# Avoiding importing application factory into module needing application context

Tags: python, api, flask, flask-restful

This question is an extension on my previous one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12373033/experimental). I was suggested to put more to explain the problem. As the heading says, *I am trying to find a way to avoid importing the application factory (create_app function) into a module that needs application context and were "import current_app as app" is not sufficient.*

My problem is I have a circular import problem due to this `create_app` function which I need to pass in order to get the app_context.

In my `__ini__.py`, I have this:

```
# application/__init__.py

from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_restful import Api
from application.resources.product import Product, Products
from application.resources.offer import Offer, Offers  # HERE IS THE PROBLEM

api = Api()
db = SQLAlchemy()

api.add_resource(Product, "/product/<string:name>")  # GET, POST, DELETE, PUT to my local database
api.add_resource(Products, "/products")  # GET all products from my local database
api.add_resource(Offer, "/offer/<int:id>")  # POST call to the external Offers API microservise
api.add_resource(Offers, "/offers")  # GET all offers from my local database


def create_app(config_filename=None):
    """ Initialize core application. """
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=False)
    app.config.from_object("config.Config")

    db.init_app(app)
    api.init_app(app)

    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()

        return app
```

The problem is in this line:

```
from application.resources.offer import Offer, Offers  # HERE IS THE PROBLEM
```

because in that module, I have:

```
#application/resources/offer.py 

from flask_restful import Resource
from application.models.offer import OfferModel  # IMPORTING OFFER MODEL
```

which in turn imports *application/models/offer.py* where I have the critical part:

```
#application/models/offer.py

import requests
# from flask import current_app as app 
from application import create_app  # THIS CAUSES THE CIRCULAR IMPORT ERROR
from sqlalchemy.exc import OperationalError

app = create_app() # I NEED TO CREATE THE APP IN ORDER TO GET THE APP CONTEXT BECASE IN THE CLASS I HAVE SOME FUNCTIONS THAT NEED IT

class OfferModel(db.Model):
    """ Data model for offers. """
    # some code to instantiate the class... + other methods..

    # THIS IS ONE OF THE METHODS THAT NEED APP_CONTEXT OR ELSE IT WILL ERROR OUT
    @classmethod
    def update_offer_price(cls):
        """ Call offers api to get new prices. This function will run in a separated thread in a scheduler. """
        with app.app_context():
            headers = {"Bearer": app.config["MS_API_ACCESS_TOKEN"]}
            for offer_id in OfferModel.offer_ids:
                offers_url = app.config["MS_API_OFFERS_BASE_URL"] + "/products/" + str(offer_id) + "/offers"
                res = requests.get(offers_url, headers=headers).json()
                for offer in res:
                    try:
                        OfferModel.query.filter_by(offer_id=offer["id"]).update(dict(price=offer["price"]))
                        db.session.commit()
                    except OperationalError:
                        print("Database does not exists.")
                        db.session.rollback()
```

I have tried to use `from flask import current_app as app` to get the context, it did not work. I don't know why it was not sufficient to pass current_app as app and get the context because it now forces me to pass the create_app application factory which causes the circular import problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your `update_offer_price` method needs database interaction and an access to the configuration. It gets them from the application context but it works only if your `Flask` application is initialized. This method is run in a separate thread so you create the *second* instance of `Flask` application in this thread.

Alternative way is getting standalone database interaction and configuration access outside the application context.

### Configuration

Configuration does not seem a problem as your application gets it from another module:

```
app.config.from_object("config.Config")
```

So you can directly import this object to your `offer.py`:

```
from config import Config

headers = {"Bearer": Config.MS_API_ACCESS_TOKEN}
```

### Database access

To get standalone database access you need to define your models via `SQLAlchemy` instead of `flask_sqlalchemy`. It was already described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41014157/6682517) but I post here the essentials. For your case it may look like this. Your `base.py` module:

```
from sqlalchemy import MetaData
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

metadata = MetaData()
Base = declarative_base(metadata=metadata)
```

And `offer.py` module:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa

from .base import Base

class OfferModel(Base):
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    # Another declarations
```

The produced `metadata` object is used to initialize your `flask_sqlalchemy` object:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

from application.models.base import metadata

db = SQLAlchemy(metadata=metadata)
```

Your models can be queried outside the application context but you need to manually create database engine and sessions. For example:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

from config import Config

from application.models.offer import Offer

engine = create_engine(Config.YOUR_DATABASE_URL)
# It is recommended to create a single engine
# and use it afterwards to bind database sessions to.
# Perhaps `application.models.base` module
# is better to be used for this declaration.

def your_database_interaction():
    session = Session(engine)
    offers = session.query(Offer).all()
    for offer in offers:
        # Some update here
    session.commit()
    session.close()
```

Note that with this approach you can't use your models classes for queriing, I mean:

```
OfferModel.query.all()  # Does not work
db.session.query(OfferModel).all()  # Works
```

Comment: uuuh. I don't know if I understand but ok, thank you very much. I will read it like five more times and maybe I will get it... It looks not a very trivial fix. - btw I was able to fix this by putting my ".. import Offer, Offers" with "api.add_resource()"  AFTER the create_app() in the __init__.py. It is sort of a hack but this way there is no circular import :-) what do u think about that?

Comment: Well, I understand it is quite a change in architecture to propose especially after the initial question with just a couple of problem lines :) Your solution solves your problem so it is ok. I don't know if it will work well after adding more logic to the application. But you should post it as an answer to your question, it is a good practice here on SO :)

Answer (score 1):

ok so this is how I solved it. I made a new file endpoints.py where I put all my Api resources

```
# application/endpoints.py    

from application import api
from application.resources.product import Product, Products
from application.resources.offer import Offer, Offers

api.add_resource(Product, "/product/<string:name>")  # GET, POST, DELETE, PUT - calls to local database
api.add_resource(Products, "/products")  # GET all products from local database.
api.add_resource(Offer, "/offer/<int:id>")  # POST call to the Offers API microservice.
api.add_resource(Offers, "/offers")  # GET all offers from local database
```

Then in init.py I import it at the very bottom.

```
# aplication/__init__.py

from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api
from db import db

api = Api()


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=False)
    app.config.from_object("config.Config")
    db.init_app(app)
    api.init_app(app)
    
    with app.app_context():
        from application import routes
        db.create_all()

        return app


from application import endpoints # importing here to avoid circular imports
```

It is not very pretty but it works.