# How can I troubleshoot my Flask app's circular import and scheduled task issues, specifically with SQLAlchemy and Twilio scheduler?

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, twilio, scheduler

I am VERY new to coding and am trying to set up a Flask App with a SQLAlchemy Database that uses Twilio to schedule daily text messages at 5 PM. I am stuck on circular imports and scheduled tasks not working properly when I try to run them in my main.py file or in my **init**.py file.

I am too junior to know really what is going on, but I have a feeling that it is related to this article:

[Circular import of db reference using Flask-SQLAlchemy and Blueprints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22929839/circular-import-of-db-reference-using-flask-sqlalchemy-and-blueprints)

My Directory so far is:

```
website
    __init__.py
    main.py
    auth.py
    keys.py
    models.py
    views.py
    static
       #Java code here
    templates
       #many html templates here
```

Here is my main.py file:

```
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app = create_app()
        app.run(debug=True)
```

Here is my models.db file:

```
from . import db
from flask_login import UserMixin
from sqlalchemy.sql import func

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    # Defining class attributes/columns
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(150), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(150))
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(150))
    phone_number = db.Column(db.String(20))
    gratitude_text_opt_in_status = db.Column(db.Boolean)
```

Here is my **init**.py file:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from os import path
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask import Flask

# create SQLAlchemy object
db = SQLAlchemy()
# set database name
DB_NAME = "database.db"

# define function to create database
def create_database(app):
    # if database file does not exist
    if not path.exists('website/' + DB_NAME):
        # create all database tables with Flask app instance
        db.create_all(app=app)
        # print message to indicate database creation
        print('Created Database!')

# define function to create Flask application
def create_app():
    # create Flask app instance with current module name
    app = Flask(__name__)
    # set secret key for app
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = #SECRET KEY#
    # set URI for database
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = f'sqlite:///{DB_NAME}'
    # initialize SQLAlchemy object with Flask app instance
    db.init_app(app)

    # import 'views' blueprint module
    from .views import views
    # import 'auth' blueprint module
    from .auth import auth``your text``

    # register 'views' blueprint with app instance
    app.register_blueprint(views, url_prefix='/')
    # register 'auth' blueprint with app instance
    app.register_blueprint(auth, url_prefix='/')

    # import User models
    from .models import User

    # create all database tables
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()

    # create LoginManager object
    login_manager = LoginManager()
    # set login view for app
    login_manager.login_view = 'auth.login'
    # initialize LoginManager object with Flask app instance
    login_manager.init_app(app)

    # define function to load user from User model by ID
    @login_manager.user_loader
    def load_user(id):
        return User.query.get(int(id))

    return app
```

Comment: What errors are you seeing?

Comment: When I try to query my database in my main.py file the error that I get is:

from .models import User
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

The code that I have at that point is:

main.py:

from .models import User

user data = User.query.filterby........(etc. etc.)